# Calculating latitude and longitude fields using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, fields-attributes, latitude-longitude

I have a shape in PostGIS that has 2,658,061 records (points).

I need to create a field that is called "Latitude" and another that is called "longitude" and calculate a position in WGS84 (SRID: 4326).

How do I do this in PostGIS?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95695/discussion-on-question-by-marcelo-esteban-lagos-bustaman-calculating-latitude-an).